# What is the Best Way to Drain a mspc channel in Rust?

Tags: rust, concurrency, channel

I need to iterate over all values that are currently stored in a receiver, and then continue with the rest of the program, which is implemented like this:

```
loop {
    match receiver.recv_timeout(std::time::Duration::from_nanos(0)) {
        Ok(value) => //do stuff with the value,
        _ => break
    }
}
```

This doesn't feel like the best / easiest way to do this. As far as I'm aware, there is no '`drain`' function in the receiver struct, and the '`iter`' method will cause the channel to pause the current thread if there are no more values in the receiver and wait for the next one.

Here is a example on how this is supposed to work:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread::spawn;
use std::thread::sleep;


let (sender,receiver) = channel();

spawn(move || {
    for i in 0..1000 {
        sender.send(i).unwrap();
        sleep(std::time::Duration::from_nanos(10));
    }
});

sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));

loop {
    match receiver.recv_timeout(std::time::Duration::from_nanos(0)) {
        Ok(value) => {
            println!("received {}", value);
        },
        _ => {
            break;
        },
    }
}
println!("done");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `try_recv` and `while let` for a more concise and clearer loop:

```rust
while let Ok(value) = receiver.try_recv() {
    println!("received {}", value);
}
```